# How to break down soap and detergents?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, water, aqueous-solution, home-experiment, solubility

I am building a greywater harvesting system. It is a 3-stage system:

- The 1st stage breaks down soap and detergents.
- The 2nd stage filters the water.
- The 3rd stage pumps water out of system.

What is the best way to break down soap and detergents in a timely manner with as few mechanical parts as possible?

Comment: When you say "break down" - do you mean chemically? What are the products that you looking for?

Comment: I highly doubt there is anything you can do in a household graywater system that would destroy detergents. Those tend to be pretty stable. You might have more luck with a skimmer if the detergents float to the top. But you'd probably have more luck asking people who do graywater systems.

Comment: |A lot of water.
|Oxygen bleach.(H2O2).
|Organic salts.
|CLR cleaner.